# What is the result of an Action and how can I use it?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Reactive Extensions have an `Observable.Start()` function.

Visual Studio tells me that it

> Invokes the action asynchronously surfacing the result through an observable sequence.

It has return type `IObservable<Unit>`

All the MDSN says about `Unit` is that it

> Represents void.

But why do I need to represent `void`?

Why do I [need to convert a stream of `void`s to list and take first element from it to replace parallel ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565446/2136963)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Reactive Extensions (or Rx) is based very strongly in functional programming, and functional programming requires that every operator returns a value.

In imperative languages, like C#, that's not the case. We can define methods without a return type like `void Foo() { ... }`. In non-functional languages this is fine, when we call `Foo()` we are expecting it to do whatever it does and have it return control to us.

In functional languages we can call `void` methods as we need everything to have a return type. So for Rx to be functional we need to have a special return type that signifies `void`, but we can't use `void` or even the actual type `System.Void`, as the return type since the compiler won't allow it. So in comes `System.Reactive.Unit` as the special type to indicate that the returned value is `void`.

And since observables are all based on `IObservable<T>` (there is no `IObservable` without `T`) you must have a return type when call `Observable.Start(Action)`. Therefore we have `IObservable<Unit>`.

I don't understand what you mean by, "Why do I need to convert a stream of voids to list and take first element from it to replace parallel ForEach?"

---

> Why not `void Start(IObservable<T>, Action<T>)`?

That signature isn't making sense to me. If you have an `Action<T>` then the overload of `Observable.Start` that applies is `IObservable<T> Observable.Start(Action<T>)`. If it is `Action` (which is the subject of your question) then it is `IObservable<Unit> Observable.Start(Action)`.

> Are there examples where Unit is used in C#, not some other languages?

This is also a question I find hard to understand. I can't possibly know every other language in enough detail to tell you where `Unit` is exclusively used in C#. In fact there are so many ports of Rx to other languages that I think there wouldn't be such a usage that you're asking for. Can you clarify what you're asking?

> There is a question linked asking where is `Parallel.ForEach(IObservable<T>, Action<T>)`. And in the answer, IObservable is queried with `ToList()` and `First()`. Which doesn't make a lot of sense for me if its only purpose is to mutate something.

The `.ToList()` operator turns an `IObservable<T>` that returns zero or more values into an `IObservable<IList<T>>` that returns one value (once the source observable completes). So the following `.First()` just turns the `IObservable<IList<T>>` into a `IList<T>`.

It has been used by the linked answer to force the execution of the observable and to block until the observable completes. Remember that observables have the same deferred execution model as enumerables.

> In functional languages, `Unit` is a compromise between pure functional paradigm and real word applications. What is its purpose in C#, which has never been purely functional?

It doesn't matter how purely functional C# is or isn't, the type `Unit` is used to allow observables, which must be strongly-type and return zero or more values, to have a type which indicates no meaningful return type.

It is very much a parallel with the `EventArgs` an event handler with the signature `void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e)` - when the event fires you know something happened, but you get no information from the `e`. Getting a value of `Unit` from an observable is very much like getting an `EventArgs` in an event handler.

Comment: Why not `void Start(IObservable<T>, Action<T>)`? Are there examples where `Unit` is used in `C#`, not some other languages? There is a question linked asking where is `Parallel.ForEach(IObservable<T>, Action<T>)`. And in the answer, `IObservable<Unit>` is queried with `ToLost()` and `First()`. Which doesn't make a lot of sense for me if its only purpose is to mutate something. In functional languages, `unit` is a compromise between pure functional paradigm and real word applications. What is its purpose in C#, which has never been purely functional?

Comment: @user2136963 - I've updated my answer based on your questions.

Comment: "Can you clarify what you're asking?" I was asking for practical usecases for c#. Now I understand, that unit is a way to monitor if an Action is completed. Thanks!

Comment: @user2136963 - Yes, that's precisely what it is. :-)